# How to move views pager to different region as a block?

Tags: 8, views, theming

I created a page view and results are showing up in main page content block. Now i need to move the pager attached with view to different region. [image: move pager to different region]

I am not sure how to achieve this. Please suggest any preprocess or backend feature which can do this?

Comment: CSS absolute positioning is one option.

Comment: @NoSssweat is there any Drupal way, any preprocess or something?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably the comment from @No SSsweat

Another easy option is to place the view in each region and hide the pager/content using CSS depending on region.

The javascript option may be possible depending if you have anything already in place, as you can move the DOM pager element programmatically.

The neater solution is to use some php code, the drupal way, probably someone has already done this for you, so look for a drupal contributed module related to view and pager or paging, and layout, those would probably be my keywords for a search.

Comment: If using CSS the best method is CSS Grid, you can shuffle elements pretty creatively with it. It can be difficult to make absolute positioning pass some accessibility tests. Depending on the situation with other content around/in-between the content and bottom content regions you might even do it with Flexbox (much easier than Grid) and that supports older browsers too.